# Screen Recording in Mac using AVFoundation's documentation

Tags: objective-c, macos, screen-recording

I have been working on screen recording on MacOS. I have working code for the same based on Apple's Documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1740/_index.html). The problem is that the resolution of the recorded video is very low. According to the logs generated it looks like SD 480x300 is the default resolution. I was unable to find any methods to change the resolution of the video quality. Can somebody help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem. You can set the screen resolution at  `mSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720;`
There are several values for the `sessionPreset` including

```
AVCaptureScreenPresetLow
AVCaptureScreenPresetMedium
AVCaptureScreenPresetHigh
AVCaptureScreenPreset320x240
AVCaptureScreenPreset352x288
AVCaptureScreenPreset640x480
AVCaptureScreenPreset960x540
AVCaptureScreenPreset1280x720
```